# Nested data in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, data-structures

First of all: I know this is a dangerous question. There are [a lot](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpandas%5D%20nested) of similar questions about storing and accessing nested data in pandas but I think my question is different (more general) so hang on. :)

I have medium sized dataset of workouts for 1 athlete. Each workout has a date and time, ~200 properties (e.g. average speed and heart rate) and some raw data (3-10 lists of e.g. speed and heart rate values per second). I have about 300 workouts and each workouts contains on average ~4000 seconds.

So far I tried 3 solutions to store this data with pandas to be able to analyze it:

1. I could use `MultiIndex` and store all data in 1 DataFrame but this
   DataFrame would get quite large (which doesn't have to be a problem
   but visually inspecting it will be hard) and slicing the data is cumbersome.
2. Another way would be to store the date and properties
   in a DataFrame `df_1` and to store the raw data in a separate
   DataFrame `df_2` that I would store in a separate column `raw_data`
   in `df_1`.
3. ...Or (similar to (2)) I could store the raw data in separate `DataFrame`s
   that I store in a `dict` with keys identical to the index of the
   `DataFrame` `df_1`.

Either of these solutions work and for this use case there are no major performance benefits to either of them. To me (1) feels the most 'Pandorable' (really like that word :) ) but slicing the data is difficult and visual inspection of the `DataFrame` (printing it) is of no use. (2) feels a bit 'hackish' and in-place modifications can be unreliable but this solution is very nice to work with. And (3) is ugly and a bit difficult to work with, but also the most Pythonic in my opinion.

**Question: What would be the benefits of each method and what is the most Pandorable solution in your opinion?**

By the way: Of course I am open to alternative solutions.

Comment: I have the same issue. Did you find a solution?

Comment: @user48956 Not really. I used method 2 for a bit and it works ok as long as you're not e.g. slicing the dataframe (then a new df is created), then this method is getting unreliable since the pointers to the second dataframe are sometimes lost. I do not really understand why/how this is happening though...